# Why is this pyspark.ml.RandomForestRegressor failing due to stopped context?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am attempting to train a `RandomForestRegressor` on a dataframe called `train` like so:

```py
rf = pyspark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor(featuresCol=self.featuresCol, labelCol=self.labelCol)
param_grid = ParamGridBuilder()\
    .addGrid(rf.numTrees, [5, 10, 20]) \
    .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [5, 10, 15]) \
    .build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=rf,
                          estimatorParamMaps=param_grid,
                          evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(),
                          numFolds=3)

self.model = crossval.fit(train)
```

Here are the number of rows in the dataframe, the number of partitions, an example row, and the dataframe schema:

```
Training on 26398 examples with 8 partitions
{'features': SparseVector(10479, {5: 1.0, 360: 1.0, 361: 0.2444, 362: -0.9697, 363: 1.0, 10476: -0.0685}),
 'label': 989}
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: long (nullable = true)
```

The final error message after trying to fit model:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 44 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
```

What can be causing this failure?

**Master**

- m4.xlarge
- 8 vCPU
- 16 GiB memory

**Workers (4 instances)**

- r4.xlarge
- 4 vCPU
- 30.5 GiB memory

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. I re-ran my training pipeline and ensured that my partitioning was more carefully managed, but it still failed due to the same reason (stopped context) so I think the partitions were a red herring.

Comment: Yes, so, just tried with 477 examples of feature vectors of length 366, and the training fails with the same error. Maybe the data resulting from preprocessing is somehow accumulating in the workers and hogging memory when I try to train the model? At this point maybe I will have to write out my dataframe to hdfs after pre-processing, then close the spark job and start a new spark context to actually train the model.